# can I hide fancybox on loading iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, popup, fancybox

I am using fancybox with iframe to implement popup windows. I solved some of the problems with patches etc. there is only one problem left. I would like to hide fancy box on loading (but loading indicator will be visible) and show it after loading. currently what I have is a blank fancy box, and after loading it resizes to iframe content. This looks ugly. I just want to show fancybox after it loads the iframe.

Answer (score 0):

set the iframe `style="display:none"`  then onpageload set it `display:block`

Comment: I was looking for a more complete answer using fancybox options and events. where do I set iframe style before loading and after loaded?, in an fancybox event or in an event in the document opened in iframe? I can figure out that kind of solution, but I don't know where to place the code (hack is the last option)

Comment: this should do it
    <iframe style="display:none;" onload="javascript:$(this).show();">